# AdMob is consuming more memory

Tags: android, memory-leaks, admob

When I am using Admob api I found it is almost increased my app processing memory to 10MB.

Running without initiating AdMob is showing only 4MB processing memory under Running Services of my App

After enabling Ads I found my App processing size is reached 14MB and it is not get decreased.

**below is my implementation code:**

```
public void initAd(){
        adView = new AdView(this, AdSize.BANNER, AD_ID);
        adLinearLayout.addView(adView);
        adView.loadAd(new AdRequest());
    }

@Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();

        if (adView != null && adView.isReady()) {

            log("destroying ads objects...");
            adView.destroy();
            adView.removeAllViews();

             adView = null;
             adLinearLayout.removeAllViews();
             adLinearLayout = null;              
        }    
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming in `onResume` or something equivalent, you're creating a new AdView.

I wouldn't use `adView.isReady()` here.  I think isReady is really only used for interstitial ads, so it may not getting set to true.  I'm not sure why it's part of the Ad interface.

Do you get the "destroying ads objects..." logging statement every time onPause is called (try logging something above the if statement to confirm)?  My guess would be that you're not actually destroying the AdView every time, but you keep creating new ones.

Comment: Thanks Eric, In my actual code I have if condition for checking the availability of existing ads instance.

If I destroy the ads object before ads get received then it will throw exceptions, to ignore that only I used iReady before destroy.

I have tried destroy ads object to reduce the memory occupied by adMob, but no luck in that.